# Can we avoid/rectify grouping by a Column when the column is used in CASE in SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has several columns out of which I would need to use few and would need to group by "truck". All other columns display number on which aggregate functions would be used.

I am using CASE statement for "load" for which values range from 0 to 7.

When I use "load" in CASE in SELECT, I have to compulsorily use "load" column in GROUP BY which spoils my results. This is the query:

```
SELECT 
truck
, CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END AS Bauxite_Loads
, CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END Waste_Loads
, CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END Rehandle_Loads
, COUNT(truck) as Total_Loads
, CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Bauxite_Tons
, CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Waste_Tons
, CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Rehandle_Tons
, SUM(loadtons) as Total_Tons
, SUM(disteh) as Empty_Distance
,SUM(distfh) as Full_Distance
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[hist_loads_new]
WHERE shiftindex = 38683
GROUP BY truck,load
```

This is what I get with the above query:
[image]

It also creates more issues when I join another table, for e.g. it joins HD62 3 times instead of 1. So, as a workaround I have to divide the value in the joined table by COUNT(truck).

This should be the expected result:
[image]

To get the expected result I have to use the below query:

```
SELECT truck, SUM(Bauxite_Loads) AS 'Bauxite Tons', SUM(Waste_Loads) AS 'Waste Tons', SUM(Rehandle_Loads) AS 'Rehandle Tons', SUM(Total_Loads) AS 'Total_Loads'
       ,SUM(Bauxite_Tons) AS 'Bauxite Tonnes', SUM(Waste_Tons) AS 'Waste Tonnes', SUM(Rehandle_Tons) AS 'Rehandle Tons', SUM(Total_Tons) AS 'Total Tons'
       ,SUM(Empty_Distance) AS 'Empty Distance', SUM(Full_Distance) AS 'Full Distance'
FROM
(
SELECT 
truck
, CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END AS Bauxite_Loads
, CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END Waste_Loads
, CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END Rehandle_Loads
, COUNT(truck) as Total_Loads
, CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Bauxite_Tons
, CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Waste_Tons
, CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Rehandle_Tons
, SUM(loadtons) as Total_Tons
, SUM(disteh) as Empty_Distance
,SUM(distfh) as Full_Distance
FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[hist_loads_new]
WHERE shiftindex = 38683
GROUP BY truck,load
) T1
GROUP BY truck
```

I am aware that column alias cannot be used in GROUP BY due the the sequence of execution of SQL statement. I also tried using the CASE statements in GROUP BY but doesn't work. I read both these work in PostgreSQL.

I need to group by "load", but not by each number, groups should be according to the 3 sets in the CASE statement (1,2,6) ,  (3,4,5) and 7.

So, is this the only way by using inline view/sub query? Or is there a way this can be achieved in a single query by tweaking the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Are you grouping by load only becuause of the error message, or is there a logical business requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregator functions need to act on the whole expression to work out like you want. This should also solve your issue with the load column.

Then you can also remove the outer select and also remove load from group by (I'm assuming it's there by mistake).

All rows like

```
CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN COUNT(truck) ELSE 0 END AS Bauxite_Loads
```

should be

```
SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bauxite_Loads
```

and

```
CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN SUM(loadtons) ELSE 0 END Bauxite_Tons
```

should be more like

```
SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN loadtons ELSE 0 END) Bauxite_Tons
```

Final select (column aliases you might want to adjust):

```
 SELECT 
 truck
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bauxite_Loads
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Waste_Loads
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Rehandle_Loads
 , COUNT(*) as Total_Loads
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (1,2,6) THEN loadtons ELSE 0 END) Bauxite_Tons
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load IN (3,4,5) THEN loadtons ELSE 0 END) Waste_Tons
 , SUM(CASE WHEN load = 7 THEN loadtons ELSE 0 END) Rehandle_Tons
 , SUM(loadtons) as Total_Tons
 , SUM(disteh) as Empty_Distance
 ,SUM(distfh) as Full_Distance
 FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[hist_loads_new]
 WHERE shiftindex = 38683
 GROUP BY truck
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. So I had to use whole expression in SELECT and then the same expression without the aggregate function (with only CASE) in GROUP BY.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you did. When the aggregator is to the left, that should be enough. Happy to help anyway. Thanks for the upvote.